# How to change the font of all page numbers in Microsoft Word 2016 for Mac?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I am writing a document in which there are several different sections in Word for Mac. I have added page numbers to all the sections. Currently the font of all the page numbers is Calibri, and I want to change the font**strong text** to Times New Roman.

Is there a way to change the font of all the page numbers in my document at once? I have looked at **Header & Footer -> Page Number -> Page Number Format**, but this does not let you customise the font of the page numbers.

[image]

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your page numbers have been inserted, you could try modifying the Page Number character style.